After trying new distro, how to move grub back to original
This is probably a pretty common problem, but searching seems to find so many different situations and answers that complicate the process for the simple case. Perhaps there is a better way to avoid it, but I don't know exactly how. I mainly run Linux Mint.
I sometimes like to try distros on a spare partition rather than a live USB. So, I install it, and it puts the GRUB menu on the new partition. Unless things have changed recently, deleting that distro will confuse GRUB, who doesn't know what happened to its menu.
I used to fix this on my desktop system by running grub-install. Then along came UEFI, GPT, etc, and I began to not understand all the parameters as well. I now have a laptop with an NVMe drive, so I'm unsure if that changes things from the old SDx naming.
I never had to use chroot or boot managers; Is there a simple way to do this?
EDIT:
I found some old notes I wrote saying to do this, assuming I want to make drive sda the active menu:
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/sda

But I don't know for sure what type of system I had at the time, like whether it was EFI, etc. It was an old tower desktop, with sata drives.
I'm really trying to avoid making my system unbootable and having to go to the trouble of fixing it, but if nobody can offer any usable suggestions, I'll forge ahead and answer my own question when I do it.

You should be able to boot into preferred install and reinstall grub. Many official flavors & unofficial flavors use "ubuntu" as UEFI boot entry, so you need the new entry with correct partUUID of ESP. If you reformatted ESP, you have to update fstab with correct UUID. Best not to reformat ESP. Similar ways to compare. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1520900/stuck-at-grub-bootloader-cli

@oldfred - I don't see how the link you provided has anything much to do with the issue I'm asking about, nor is that issue resolved; it seems like it was abandoned. All I want to do is delete the partition with the current GRUB menu, and use the old GRUB menu for the still existing system that I use.

Can you boot into preferred install? Then check UUID in fstab to be sure ESP is mounted correctly. If changing UUID in fstab, you need to make sure it is updated with sudo mount -a or a reboot. Then you just need sudo grub-install or use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose install & drive to install grub into. You can always check UEFI entries with sudo efibootmgr or sudo efibootmgr -v Newer versions seem to give too much info with -v, but older versions need -v to see partUUID to know which ESP is used by your UEFI.

@oldfred - Thanks for the suggestion, but I might not have made myself clear. The Ubuntu documentation describes the problem clearly:
"The user may wish to reinstall GRUB 2 for a variety of reasons, including:

After installing another operating system which installed its own bootloader, reinstall GRUB2 to return control to the desired OS. When an operating system is added on a multiboot computer it will generally take command of the boot process. Reinstalling GRUB 2 from a within the desired OS will return control of the boot process to that OS. "


Continued... They say to simply run "sudo grub-install /dev/sdX", much as I posted, but I'm not sure if having NVMe drive makes a difference. Probably not, and I may just take the plunge and try it. I fortunately am not dependent on this system now.

Big difference. And depends is UEFI or BIOS. And if running from inside your install or from a live installer. If inside your install you do not have to specify a device if UEFI and correct ESP is mounted as posted before. And if specifying device it will be /dev/lnvme0n1 if your first NVMe drive. But it must be mounted & generally chroot or Boot-Repair help. And seen some with installs on second NVMe drive.  chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088

Understood. Thanks for the comments. I was probably just overthinking it. All the OSs are on one 2dGB NVMe drive, and I don't use BIOS if I have a choice, so it should be easy.  In the old days, I could do it even if it was a different drive and not already mounted, but that was the simpler times.

So, it turns out it was very easy to do; I was overthinking the problem fearing a need to do a boot repair. For future readers, I'll to make this clear, and go through the situation.
One thing to understand, which many newbies might not, is that GRUB has two parts. The bootloader part is loaded first, and it has been told where to look for its menu, which is in the last OS installed, if Linux. So, you can have a GRUB menu in every OS, but only one of them will be used. If you make a change that doesn't seem to work, it may be the wrong menu.
The problem
The problem is described in the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki, at Grub 2 installation, down the page under the heading Reinstalling GRUB 2. The first item describes this problem, which is fairly common, and has caused a lot of new users much consternation when they try out a distro, then delete the partition and can no longer boot their system.
The Wiki describes it thusly:

The user may wish to reinstall GRUB 2 for a variety of reasons, including:
After installing another operating system which installed its own bootloader, reinstall GRUB2 to return control to the desired OS. When an operating system is added on a multiboot computer it will generally take command of the boot process. Reinstalling GRUB 2 from a within the desired OS will return control of the boot process to that OS.


The Solution

The solution depends on the situation, but the most common one is where there is one hard drive containing any number of OS's. This is a simple fix, if you are able to boot into the old system (ie, you have not yet deleted the new partition). You just boot, and run the command
sudo grub-install disk name


"disk name" is the name of the disk containing the systems. I use the disk utility to find the name, or gparted. There are numerous other ways. If you have a traditional sata drive, it is probably "/dev/sda". Note this is the name for the disk, not a partition. The utility knows where it is. For my laptop with the NVMe drive, it was called "/dev/nvme0n1p1".
The output of the command is somewhat anti-climatic and fast, assuming success. You should follow this with
sudo update-grub


But what if you can't boot into the desired OS because you already deleted the partition containing the GRUB menu? You will then need an alternate OS you can boot, such as the live installation CD/USB. You boot this system, then check for the name of the disk you want to repair, which is probably the same as previously mentioned, such as "/dev/sda". There is an extra step now; you need to mount the partition containing the working OS that you want to boot. Note you will need both the disk and the partition, such as "/dev/sda5" for mounting that partition (remember, you mount partitions, not disks). A common mount point is "/mnt", so as an example, using that mount point and the aforementioned /dev/sda5, the command would be:
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda


You should have the old menu, but if you need to update the menu, you will need to chroot to /mnt and run update-grub (sudo chroot /mnt). I don't remember the details for this part.
